# Possible to call function by string name

Tags: lua

```
function AIORotation:SetRotation(val)
    if val == "abcd" then
        self.db.profile.activeRotation = AIORotation.aaaa:new()
    elseif val == "dddd" then
        self.db.profile.activeRotation = AIORotation.dddd:new()
    end
end
```

I am passing a string into this function and want to call a function based off the string name.  Is something like this possible without a bunch of if statements?

So ideally, it would be something like this

```
function AIORotation:SetRotation(val)
    self.db.profile.activeRotation = AIORotation.<INSERT_VAL_HERE>:new()
end
```

But I'm not sure if something like this is possible in lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `[]` syntax. `[]` syntax allows you to use any variable, expression (that evaluates on runtime) or constant.

```lua
function AIORotation:SetRotation(val)
    self.db.profile.activeRotation = AIORotation[val]:new()
end
```

`.var` syntax is actually identical to `["var"]` (syntactic sugar).

Read move about table syntax: https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html